# c++ opencv/qt method to get width/height of character/word in pixels

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Basically what I need to do is fit text perfectly within an area and for that I need to be able to get the 'size' of a word (or character). Note that this project needs to be compiled on both linux and windows. I believe `TextRenderer::MeasureTextMethod` can solve my problem but apparently it is windows specific. Need a way to do this in linux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QFontMetrics` class. You can find size of characters or strings. Also this class has many another useful methods.

Example:

```
 QFont font("times", 24);
 QFontMetrics fm(font);
 int pixelsWide = fm.width("What's the width of this text?");
 int pixelsHigh = fm.height();
```

Link: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html

Of course, it is cross-platform.